# how to query database for each day in an array of days laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array of days that I want to query my model for each date that I have in that array, that could be possible with a for loop and index but as thumbs rules I don't want to query inside a loop so is there any other possibility to check the date in my model so my tried with for loop is like below :

```php
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($from_date, $to_date);
$dates = $period->toArray();
// and here l am looping the days :
for ($t = 0; $t < count($dates); $t++) {
    $room_capacity = Capacity::with('Hotel')
        ->where('room_id', $room_ids[$i])
        ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $dates[$t])
        ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $dates[$t])
        ->get()->sortBy('created_at');
}
```

I want to know if there is any way to optimize the above code not to write it inside a loop. thanks

Comment: What is the final information that you need with this query? What is the attributes of Capacity model?

Comment: @JeanMarcos Yes this the final data i need

Answer (score 3):

The room_id condition persists in the loop & you are looping through dates. So maybe you can use "or condition" for the dates, something like this:

```
$room_capacity = Capacity::with('Hotel')
    ->where('room_id', $room_ids[$i])
    ->where(function (Builder $query) use ($dates) {
        for ($t = 0; $t < count($dates); $t++) {
            $date = $dates[$t];
            $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $date)
                    ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $date);
            });
        }
    })->get()->sortBy('created_at');
```